# Element wise multiplication of two list that are tf.Tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

What is the fastest way to do an element-wise multiplication between a tensor and an array in Tensorflow 2?

For example, if the tensor `T` (of type tf.Tensor) is:

```
[[0, 1],  
[2, 3]]
```

and we have an array `a` (of type np.array):

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

I wand to have:

```
[[[0, 0],  
  [0, 0]],  
  
 [[0, 1],  
  [2, 3]],  
 
 [[0, 2],  
  [4, 6]]]
```

as output.

Comment: That not element-wise multiplication, that's an outer product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two tensors. It's easy to compute by taking advantage of Tensorflow's [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting) rules:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3]]) 
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])

# (2,2) x (3,1,1) produces the desired shape of (3,2,2)
result = t * a.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
# Alternatively: result = t * a[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

print(result)
```

results in

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 2],
        [4, 6]]], dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 2):

In [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), we have [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) and can use this like below:

```
>>> a = tf.reshape(tf.range(4), (2,2))
>>> b = tf.range(3)
>>> tf.tensordot(b,a, axes=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 2],
        [4, 6]]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't unique to tensorflow. Numpy also has [`numpy.tensordot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot), which works in the the same way.

Comment: Am I saying anything? OP tag [tag:tensorflow] and want tensorflow function. Does OP tags [tag:numpy]?

Comment: And do you have any idea what is fastest between tensordot function and the outer product?

Comment: @LorisPilotto, you can check the time of this approach and any other approach with `%timeit` before each line, for this approach you can check with a large array-like `%timeit tf.tensordot(b,a, axes=0)` in Jupyter or [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the array and perform a scalar multiplication with the tensor values:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3]])
a = [0, 1, 2]

u = []
for i in a:
    u.append(t.numpy()*i)
u = tf.constant(u)
print(u)
```

**Output:**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0 0]
  [0 0]]

 [[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[0 2]
  [4 6]]], shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Also, you can use list comprehension as follows to get a more *`readable`* code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3]])
a = [0, 1, 2]

u = tf.constant([t.numpy()*i for i in a])
print(u)
```